# What are the speeds of light inside a retarder?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization

A retarder introduces a phase shift between the field components traveling along the fast axis and the slow axis. But at what speeds are they actually traveling? Is the speed of light along the fast axis simply equal to the typical speed of light in the material?

Answer (score 0):

It’s always the case that the speed of light in a medium is $c/n$. So you can figure out the speed (phase velocity) that way. If the material is birefringent, such as in a typical retarder, then $n$ is slightly different depending on the electric field direction.